# Python installing package MAC OS X

Tags: python, macos, package, pip

I am trying to install the package requests in my Mac OS X but I got in trouble. In the First time I installed it using "pip install requests" but I got some exceptions during the installation time and the package was not installed correct. In this way I am still not able to use it in my code but when I try to install it again I get a message saying it is already installed. Even that the folder do not exist. I already tried to uninstall python and requests package but I was not able to do it. PS: I am new at MACs...

http://postimg.org/image/sc0ooqfit/

Comment: Did you try `pip install --upgrade requests`, as the error message suggests? Also, about "got some exceptions" - we can't help unless you post them. Finally, please include all relevant information in the post itself; a screencap might be accompanying, but the text is what we primarily want to see.

Comment: The problem seems to be that ``requests`` is installed for the system Python 2, but your IDE uses Python 3. You need to either install ``requests`` for your Py3, or switch your IDE to use Py2.

Comment: Amadan I got some exceptions. but because I am not able to install requests again I am not able to print screen this exceptions.

http://postimg.org/image/6y886jxtn/

Fjarri, I tried pip-2.7 install requests, and sudo easy_install requests but I was not able to do it work. in pip-2.7 I got invalid command.

Comment: To manage your python packages (installing different version of python, each with different packages, at the same time on the same machine), use:
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv#installation
and:
https://github.com/yyuu/pyenv-virtualenv
Installation instructions and how-tos are found in these links as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I can see you are using Pycharm IDE and it is using python 3 as its default interpreter.

You can either install requests via pycharm itself:
Go to Pycharm -> Preferences -> Default Project -> Project Interpreter -> Click on '+', search for 'requests' and click 'Install Package'

Or you can change interpreter to python 2.7 via the same 'Project Interpreter' section (just select it via dropdown). And you already have requests installed in your python 2.7 packages.

Answer (score 0):

Since Mac is pre-installed with Python2, you might have installed requests with Python2 if you didn't modify the path for Python3 as the first preference.

I would suggest you downloading requests directly here
https://github.com/kennethreitz/requests/zipball/master

and install it with Python3 in the command line manually.

Answer (score 0):

This answer is kinda overkill but after the hassle of package management woes the best answer I can give you is: "download Anaconda"  http://continuum.io/downloads  as it already has Python + 150 libraries including Requests, and getting most of the package you want is made simpler with the Conda tool.

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. The log said it failed to create a directory "error: could not create `'/Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/requests':` Permission denied".

Realized at that point the the problem was that I need to be root to do the install.

For me the answer was `"sudo pip install requests"`